# myProcess.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero for a process with a form that is visible? [C#]

Tags: c#

I have a windows service (Serv.exe) running as LocalSystem, at a certain point it wants to show the logged-on user that it is processing data, therefore I CreateProcessAsUser(Display.exe) which is a C# Windows Form that display information (this all works perfectly fine).

Now, when the Service is finished I want to close Display.exe - from reading around there are 2 general options. Either kill the process (which works fine in my case, but is not recommended) or use the myProcess.CloseMainWindow(); which I am currently trying to implement.

Here is my code:

```
            Process[] myProcesses;
            myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("Display");
            foreach (Process myProcess in myProcesses)
            {
                if (myProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    myProcess.Kill();
                }
                else
                {
                    myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
                }
            }
```

Now, Display is simply a C# Windows Form application, I can see it on screen and my code is able to find the process (as killing it works fine) - but why is myProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero? I've tried adding 15 second sleep (incase the form was still loading) but it made no difference.

Is there something I need to implement in Display.exe itself to process the .CloseMainWindow()? Can this have something to do with the fact that my Service (Serv.exe) running as LocalSystem is trying to get the MainWindowHandle for a process running under a different user?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you're running as a service, you're not in the same session as the display window, so it's not able to get the window handle of the child process.

Comment: So - is the only way to actually KILL the process? Can I send it a message or something to shut it down gracefully?

Comment: You'll need some other mechanism to communicate with it. Sockets, RPC, trigger files, etc. Window messages are out, though. Just killing it is probably the safest thing, as there isn't any real data loss that will result from a display process dying.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - Windows Messages are out because I am running as a Service trying to message a processs running as a USER?

What about spawning another process CreateProcessAsUser(...) to do the .CloseMainWindow()?